# Shadow isn't casted on object

Tags: mesh, objects, light, lighting, shadows

I'm making an animation of Solar system and shadows of all planets are shown, except Saturns rings which have no shadows¸, although there's no light from the Sun coming to the certain parts of the rings. For Saturns rings I used torus.

[image]

But when I position the torus at a certain angle, it's completely dark.

[image]

This is torus' node tree.

[image]

And this is the node tree for every other planet.

[image]

My render engine is **Cycles**.

**What could be the cause?**

*Thank you!*

Comment: Hi, quick question: Do you use Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: @DarkSoul Cycles

Comment: Did you try delete material so default one is used? Does issue persists? If nobody see issue you should post simplified blend file only with issue part still visible via blend-exchange site

Comment: Could it just be that the torus is tilted towards the sun so the backside of it is completely dark?

Comment: @stphnl329 Torus is either completely light on one side of it and completely dark on the other one

Comment: @vklidu No matter which material I put, torus is completely dark on one side, and completely colored on the other one

Comment: Properties Editor > Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Shadow is enabled for Sphere? If so, attach blend with sphere and torus without materials. Thanks

Comment: @vklidu Which Sphere? Do you mean Sun or a certain planet?

Comment: Another question: What light source do you use? Is it an object with an emission shader or a light object?

Comment: @DarkSoul At the beggining I used Emission, but it didn't turn out as I imagined, so I used the Point light and placed it in the middle of the Sun   and two Spot lights under and above the Sun

Comment: @Dino Držinić: First -you could check properties of both spheres instead of asking, it is much faster. Second - I asked you twice to post a blend file with deleted all parts that doesn't related to the issue (via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com), if it wasn't clear yet. Like now you are waiting already four days for something that could be already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a similair setup and it seems to work for me.[image]

As you can see, I also made use of a light source and put this inside the Sun sphere. There Are several things you need to check.

1) First of all you need to ensure if your light source has shadows enabled. You can check that out in the next image. Select your light source.

[image]

2) If you also decide to have the light source inside your Sun, you need to make sure the shadow of the Sun sphere is disabled as seen in the next image. Select your Sun.

[image]

3) Third thing to make sure is that you planet is casting the shadows on the rings. See here:

[image]

I've added a copy of the blend file:

[image]

Hope this helps!